# How do I find the circumcenter of a triangle in 3D?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I want to find the circumcenter of a triangle.  Wolfram only shows [how to find the circumcircle of a triangle in R<sup>2</sup>](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html). How can I find the circumcenter of a triangle in R<sup>3</sup>?

Comment: You can define a plane using the 3 points of a triangle and then the problem is back into R^2 for which you already know the method.

Comment: @Ani The [formulae for circumcircle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html) involve only x and y, but a 3D triangle, in 3-space plane, uses x, y and z variables.

Comment: what I meant was a unique plane can be defined using the 3 vertex of the triangle and in that reference plane, the triangle is 2D. This will however require appropriate transforms (which I did not elaborate) and hence just put this as a guiding comment rather than answer

Comment: Yes, in fact I thought I was going to have to rotate the triangle to the xy/xz/yz plane, then apply the 2d formula.  Hence why I shared the Triangle in R^3 formula I found at Geometry Junkyard below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The circumcenter of a triangle can be found by the following formula, which I mined from an old posting by Jonathan Shewchuk from the [Geometry Junkyard](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/circumcenter.html)

$$\begin{align}
&\text{Triangle in } \Bbb R^3\text{:}\\
&m = a + \frac {\lVert c-a\rVert^2 \left[(b-a) \times (c - a) \right] \times (b-a) + \lVert b-a\rVert^2 \left[(c-a) \times (b - a) \right] \times (c-a)}
{2 \lVert (b - a) \times (c - a) \rVert^2}
\end{align}$$

Where \$m\$ is the circumcenter of the triangle.

Some C++ code, given Vector3f's with overloaded +, -,

```
Vector3f a,b,c // are the 3 pts of the tri

Vector3f ac = c - a ;
Vector3f ab = b - a ;
Vector3f abXac = ab.cross( ac ) ;

// this is the vector from a TO the circumsphere center
Vector3f toCircumsphereCenter = (abXac.cross( ab )*ac.len2() + ac.cross( abXac )*ab.len2()) / (2.f*abXac.len2()) ;
float circumsphereRadius = toCircumsphereCenter.len() ;

// The 3 space coords of the circumsphere center then:
Vector3f ccs = a  +  toCircumsphereCenter ; // now this is the actual 3space location
```

Here is a picture of a triangle and its circumsphere

[image]

Comment: len2() is squared length ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript - MY WORK - 5 TRIANGLE CENTERS IN 3D

```
function incenter(A,B,C) {
    var a=vlen(subv(A,B)),b=vlen(subv(B,C)),c=vlen(subv(C,A));
    var x = multv(C,a), y = multv(A,b), z = multv(B,c);
    return divv(addallv(x,y,z),a+b+c);
}

function centroid(A,B,C) {
    return divv(addallv(A,B,C),3);
}

function midpoint(A,B) {
    return divv(addv(A,B),2);
}

function orthocenter(A,B,C) {
    var c = circumcenter(A,B,C);
    return addallv(subv(A,c),subv(B,c),subv(C,c),c);
}

function circumcenter(A,B,C) {
    var z = crossprod(subv(C,B),subv(A,B));
    var a=vlen(subv(A,B)),b=vlen(subv(B,C)),c=vlen(subv(C,A));
    var r = ((b*b + c*c - a*a)/(2*b*c)) * outeradius(a,b,c);
    return addv(midpoint(A,B),multv(normaliz(crossprod(subv(A,B),z)),r));
}

function nine_point(A,B,C) {
    return midpoint(orthocenter(A,B,C),circumcenter(A,B,C));
}

function outeradius(a,b,c) { /// 3 lens
    return (a*b*c) / (4*sss_area(a,b,c));
}

function sss_area(a,b,c) {
    var sp = (a+b+c)*0.5;
    return Math.sqrt(sp*(sp-a)*(sp-b)*(sp-c));
    //semi perimeter
}
```

If you need the remaining functions, you can fint them in this 
[working code example](http://trueinnerbeing.x10host.com/pool/pool.html) - hit the pyramid button twice.

[image: Screenshot of pool example linked above after clicking Pyramid button]

Comment: This isn't a good answer. You use a lot of functions, that aren't self explanatory and aren't included in vanilla JS. `divv`, `addallv`, etc.

Comment: @Bálint since the question asks for an algorithm, not tagged with a specific language, I think this is no worse than the accepted answer that assumes a suitable definition of `Vector3f` in a C++ program. That answer doesn't define the `cross` or `len2` methods, but we can infer they're the cross product and squared length reasonably easily, just the way in this answer we can infer that `addallv` sums the provided vector arguments, and `divv` does scalar multiplication between a vector and the reciprocal of a scalar. I certainly wouldn't complain about more explanation, but it's legible as-is.

Comment: thanks for the help but its find not fint. and its more than "twice."  (more models)

Comment: hmf, looks like gravity was busted, found the error. Sorry, get the new file. and ctrl-f5 is supposed to reload but ... oh well. and given the response well ... I know better. no good deed goes ... outta here. make something cool and quit asking questions. all u need is one good program and your done asking questions.

Comment: "I think this is no worse than the accepted answer that assumes" uhm, you wont ever see a better more complete example for triangles centers, and if you ever do, call me lol

Comment: also you wont see all 7 sin/cos laws as working functions like this. which I wrote of course but dont know where to post it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Unity/C#
Vector3 ac = c - a;
Vector3 ab = b - a;
Vector3 abXac = Vector3.Cross(ab, ac);

// this is the vector from a TO the circumsphere center
Vector3 toCircumsphereCenter = (Vector3.Cross(abXac,ab) * ac.sqrMagnitude + Vector3.Cross(ac,abXac) * ab.sqrMagnitude) / (2f * abXac.sqrMagnitude);
float circumsphereRadius = toCircumsphereCenter.magnitude;

// The 3 space coords of the circumsphere center then:
Vector3 ccs = a + toCircumsphereCenter; // now this is the actual 3space location
```

[image]

Comment: This answer can be improved with additional content rather than having just a code snippet not everyone might understand.